# Zip Exception: Entry is not named while unzipping the zip file

Tags: android, unzip, zipinputstream

I have downloaded the zip file and when I am unzipping the files I am getting the above exception.
Below is my structure after I have unzipped my zip file.

zip structure(After unzip):
      folder1
       subfolder1
             sub1
             sub2
       subfolder2
            subf1
            subf2

```
 String inputPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+arrayListQuestions.get(0).getQuestion_asset_name();

            Log.e("inputPath",inputPath);
            String outputPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/unzip/";
            Log.e("outPath",outputPath);
ZipManager zipManager = new ZipManager();
        try {
            zipManager.unzip(inputPath, outputPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("error_unzip",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

UnzipFunction:

public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
        File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
        if (!destDir.exists()) {
            destDir.mkdir();
            }
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        // iterates over entries in the zip file
        while (entry != null) {
            String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                // if the entry is a file, extracts it
                extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
                } else {
                // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                dir.mkdir();
                }
            zipIn.closeEntry();
            entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
            }
        zipIn.close();
        }


    private void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
            }
        bos.close();
        }
```

Comment: Please add stack trace of the error

Comment: its saying Entry is not named

Comment: did you sort this? i have same problem

Comment: @Gillardo No I have tried some different code.

Comment: @dev_ry i am having real trouble trying to zip files... doesnt seem to work.  Dont suppose u know the library you used?

Comment: @Gillardo you are unzipping right?

Comment: @dev_ry zipping and unzipping.  My unzipping code was throwing this error, but i am having trouble with zipping to.

Comment: @Gillardo Well I get back to you if I find the code

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [ZipFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile) instead of `ZipInputStream`. `ZipFile` appears to handle name-less [local file headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Local_file_header) gracefully.

Note that the disadvantage of ZipFile is that it cannot process arbitrary `InputStream`s and only takes files.

Also note that the problem appears to be specific to Android. I don't get this exception with Oracle's JRE.